# Run a macro on multiple files at the same time programmatically

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which I use to run a macro on an excel file. I pass the file name and location as well the macro name and location as inputs to this program. the program takes the file and the macro , opens them, runs the macro and closes the files and excel apps. this works fine.

Now the problem arises at production when I get hundreds of such files at the same time , and all try to access the same macro. In most of the cases I get 'COM Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC’ indicating the macro is already in use . My program handles this exception. While on the other occasions I do not get any exception but all the excel instances just remain in a hung state.

Please help me in understanding if there is a way to run the same macro on multiple workbooks at the same time and how to achieve this programmatically. Providing an example of my code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oBook1 = null;
oBook1 = oBooks.Open(fileFullPath, 0, false, 5, Request.Password, "", true, 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
    false, 0, true, false, false);
oExcel.Run(....);
oBook1.Save();
oBook1.close;
oExcel.quit;
```

If this is not possible programmatically , please help me in any sort of workaround which would throw an exception/error back to the program so it exists gracefully rather than just crashing.

Comment: Have you tried instead of a macro - coding the macro in c# so it operates it on each excel workbook.. rather than trying to run the same macro on each workbook which it clearly doesnt want to

Comment: I cant write macro code in the program because my program is a WCF service which caters to many different files and macros. So writing the macro code in the program itself is not feasible for each and every of them

Comment: have you considered making queues so you only process 1 of each kind at a time?

Comment: how to make the queue? in the macro or in the code which is calling the macro?

Comment: code that calls the macro - any queue will do, just have a queue so you process items while theres stuff in the queue so only ever 1 of each macro type is running